# How can I add background pic on my messenger lite's chat?

Tags: apk

I'm using "**Apk Editor Pro**" I know how to add background pic on activity login and activity_main page but still I can't add in chat on messenger lite, so can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the link of the "Apk Editor Pro"?

Comment: Sure I downloaded it from apptoid, here's the link https://apk-editor-pro.en.aptoide.com/app

Comment: [Parsa Samie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14785437) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65195544) saying "Have you tried change the image "background_hd" ?"